# Show logs only from one class using logback

Tags: logback

I am trying to display logs into console as well as file however in file i want only certain logs that will be displayed from one particular class and i am not sure how to do this. Below is my logback.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>

<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>{ "date_time":"%date", "thread":"[%thread]", "log_level":"%-5level", "class_name":"%logger{0}", "log_message":"%msg" }%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file> test.txt </file>
    <append>false</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>{ "date_time":"%date", "thread":"[%thread]", "log_level":"%-5level", "class_name":"%logger{0}", "log_message":"%msg" }%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just declare a `logger` for your "one particular class" and then associate that logger with your `FILE` appender.

For example:

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>test.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>{ "date_time":"%date", "thread":"[%thread]", "log_level":"%-5level", "class_name":"%logger{0}", "log_message":"%msg" }%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="your.particular.Class">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</root>
```

This will ensure that any log events emitted by `your.particular.Class` are **only** directed to the `FILE` appender and all other logs will be directed **only** to the `STDOUT` appender.